# Plot specific values on x axis using plot() in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have some points:

```
a=c(1.234, 23.332, 3.433, 34.53)

b=c(112, 234, 221, 23)
```

I would like to plot them by having "a" on the x axis and "b" on the y axis.

```
plot(a,b)
```

This will give the resulting plot, but what I would like to do is rather than display some interval on the x axis I would like to display the exact numbers that I have, i.e. the values of a.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Jup.

```
plot(a,b, xaxt="n")
axis(side=1, at=a)
```

or maybe

```
axis(side=1, at=round(a,2))
```

for aesthetical reasons.